# How to save an Excel file with a path in the app.config

Tags: c#, excel, save, app-config, filepath

I want to save an Excel file in the path that was provided in the `app.config`.

I tried to insert the path the in `app.config` as:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key = "savingPath " value= "C:\Desktop"/>
</appSettings>
```

and as for the saving of the workbook:

```
private const string SavingPath = "savingPath";
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SavingPath];
Workbook.SaveAs(@"path");
```

The Excel file should be saved in the `Desktop` folder as configured in the `app.config`.

Comment: Well, you save to a file named "path" instead of saving it in _path_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick the value from `App.config` using `ConfigurationManager` class

```
private const string SavingPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["savingPath"];
Workbook.SaveAs(SavingPath);
```

Comment: It says: 'The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:

• Make sure the specified folder exists. 
• Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
• Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
• Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.'

Comment: @mariatherez, then make sure the specified folder (`SavingPath` value) exists, then make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only, then make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters: `<`, `>`, `?`, `[`, `]`, `:`, `|` or `*`, and finally make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters

Comment: @mariatherez you may need to specify a file name - currently your path only points to a folder. So `Workbook.SaveAs(SavingPath + "\\test.xlsx");`

Comment: Directory.CreateDirectory(SavingPath) will create a directory. You'll need to extract the .xlsx file path from that though as it creates a directory and not a file.